# Topological space and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{B}(X)$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology $\tau$.

I know that the topology $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary (possibly uncountable) unions, while the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is only closed under countable unions. I'm a little confused about the following: how can $\mathcal{B}(X)$ contain $\tau$, but is only closed under countable unions? Can someone shed some lights on it (maybe provide a small example for the the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?)

Comment: If $E$ is a non-Borel set, then singleton sets in $E$ are all Borel sets but their union is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal B(X)$ being closed under countable unions doesn't mean it is ***forbidden*** to contain an uncountable union.  It simply means that uncountable unions are not, in general, ***required*** to be in $\mathcal B(X)$.  Some uncountable unions may happen to still lie in the $\sigma$-algebra anyway, which is fine.

geetha290krm's comment gives an example of an uncountable union of Borel sets that is not Borel - namely, take any non-Borel set to begin with, and consider the singletons that make up that set. So this indicates that uncountable unions are not always $\mathcal B(X)$.  Note that this example supposes singletons are Borel sets, which follows whenever, for example, the underlying topology $\tau$ is $T_1$, meaning singletons are closed, and presumes the existence of a non-Borel set, [which is the case in $\mathbb R$ for example.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/217325/1210477)

But of course, an open set in $\mathbb R$, for example, is an uncountable union of singletons, which does happen to still be a Borel set.